# python setting state of a future

Tags: python, future, concurrent.futures

Is it bad practice to set the state of future to pass arguments?
Specifically using something like `future.q = q` to use `q` in the callback

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import RLock
from threading import current_thread
from concurrent.futures import Future
import time
import random

class NonBlockingQueue:

    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.q = []
        self.q_waiting_puts = []
        self.q_waiting_gets = []
        self.lock = RLock()

    def enqueue(self, item):

            future = None
            with self.lock:
                curr_size = len(self.q)

                # queue is full so create a future for a put
                # request
                if curr_size == self.max_size:
                    future = Future()
                    self.q_waiting_puts.append(future)

                else:
                    self.q.append(item)

                    # remember to resolve a pending future for
                    # a get request
                    if len(self.q_waiting_gets) != 0:
                        future_get = self.q_waiting_gets.pop(0)
                        future_get.set_result(self.q.pop(0))

            return future


    def retry_enqueue(future):
        print("\nCallback invoked by thread {0}".format(current_thread().getName()))
        item = future.item
        q = future.q
        new_future = q.enqueue(item)

        if new_future is not None:
            new_future.item = item
            new_future.q = q
            new_future.add_done_callback(retry_enqueue)
        else:
            print("\n{0} successfully added on a retry".format(item))



### MAIN CODE
def producer_thread(q):
    item = 1
    while 1:
        future = q.enqueue(item)
        if future is not None:
            future.item = item
            future.q = q
            future.add_done_callback(retry_enqueue)

        item += 1

        # slow down the producer
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to pass around arguments like this.

The reason is that in future (no pun), they could just disallow setting custom attributes on the `Future` object, which will break your code.

Better solution is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or `lambda` to pass extra arguments to the callback.

First, accept `q` as an argument in the `retry_enqueue` function:

```py
def retry_enqueue(future, q): # accept 'q' argument
    ...
```

Example using `functools.partial`:

```py
import functools

future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(retry_enqueue, q=q))
```

Example using `lambda`:

```py
future.add_done_callback(lambda future: retry_enqueue(future, q))
```